How to upgrade MongoDB version that comes with Meteor 1.8.1
I am having an issue where my live app deployed to Galaxy is not acting the same way as my local version. See this question.
I checked the MongoDB version locally, and it says it is version 4.0.6 which I am guessing is the version of MongoDB that comes with Meteor 1.8.1 (I never installed MongoDB on Windows 10).
When I checked the cluster version on Mongo Atlas, it states 5.0.26. Not sure if this is the MongoDB version but I guess it is. So I am assuming I need to upgrade my local MongoDB version to match this so that I can replicate the issue locally.
I have scoured the internet for simple instructions on how to upgrade the MongoDB version that ships with Meteor, to no avail. Not even sure if this is possible. I don't really want to upgrade Meteor version as this would likely lead to many other issues.
How can I upgrade the local MongoDB version (without losing data), from 4.0.6 to 5.0.26?

Meteor comes bundled with a specific mongoDB version. I am not sure if you can upgrade it (you should rather upgrade the Meteor app) but you can use the MONGO_URL and MONGO_OPLOG_URL environment variables to point to a different MongoDB instance even on local. However, beware the Mongo JS driver may not be compatible with the other Major version.

As JanKapunkt has stated, Meteor comes packed with MongoDB for local development. You can install any MongoDB version on your own system and use the MONGO_URL and MONGO_OPLOG_URL env variables to direct your Meteor to use that instead. You then have to be careful that the MongoDB driver that Meteor uses is compatible with the version of MongoDB that you want to use.
That said, you should really upgrade your Meteor version. At the time of writing Meteor 1.8.1 is 5 years old. Go to Meteor docs changelog and see what has changed from version to version.
Meteor for most versions has little to no breaking changes, so you should be able to upgrade quiet a few versions without encountering any issues. You can also reach out on the official Meteor forums for help on anything you encounter. The more you delay upgrades, the more issues you are going to have. You should be able to easily upgrade to Meteor 1.12.1 and even beyond. Things get challenging with Meteor 3 which requires quiet a few changes. But once you get to higher versions you will also be able to upgrade to more modern versions of MongoDB.
